# auth0: failed to resolve com.auth0.android:lock

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, auth0

I am following the auth0-documentation, I created a new project, targeting Android 6, but the very first step does not work:

```
compile 'com.auth0.android:lock:2.0.0'
```

results in

> failed to resolve com.auth0.android:lock:2.0.0

after syncing gradle.

Where am I going wrong?

PS: In case you want me to post source-code here... I did not write any! I just wrote that one line in my gradle build-file

Comment: post the relevant code

Comment: I did not write any code yet :-), I just wrote that one line

Comment: compile 'com.auth0.android:lock:1.16.+'

Comment: The `auth0/Lock.Android` repo readme file indicates to use the library add the following line: `compile 'com.auth0.android:lock:1.16.+'` - https://github.com/auth0/Lock.Android

Comment: where did you find any reference to 2.0.0

Comment: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/android

Comment: The whole tutorial at https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/android is kind of iffy.. there are Strings without paratheses, obviously untested code and so on...

Comment: I saw `auth0` advertising for a technical writer position re: documentation etc. and I saw a similar issue raised in their repo regarding documentation mismatch between readme file and their official documentation.

Comment: The code afaik isn't untested. Its using an unpublished module.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `compile 'com.auth0.android:lock:2.0.0-beta.3'`

or just `compile 'com.auth0.android:lock:2.+'`

[auth0 / lock-android / lock / 2.0.0-beta.3](https://bintray.com/auth0/lock-android/lock/2.0.0-beta.3)

> for me it failed on API 19 device, works on API 23.

update: the problem was in bug with vector graphics in KitKat API.
using changing default header icon helps to resolve the problem.

one of way:

```
  <style name="AppTheme.Lock.Theme" parent="Lock.Theme">
    <item name="Auth0.HeaderLogo">@drawable/app_logo</item>
  </style>
```

with changing activity theme in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
      android:name="com.auth0.android.lock.LockActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Lock.Theme">
```

and

```
 //here is your header logo res
 int headerLogo = R.drawable.app_logo;
```

..

```
 Theme theme = Theme.newBuilder()
    .withHeaderLogo(headerLogo)        
    .build();
```

..

```
 this.lock = Lock.newBuilder(auth0, callback)
    .withTheme(theme)
    .build();
```

Comment: With the new beta4 they removed the 'withTheme()' call. Do you know how to change logo/title after these changes?